# Iterate a For Loop from bottom to top to delete rows

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a range of cells where each cell contains a different value (Call this **range1**) and looks against a template file.
I copy all sheets of the template file (3 sheets), these first 2 steps work.

I need to loop from the bottom to top and look on all 3 sheets to delete all rows where the value in a column (Call this **range2**) <> the value in Range1.

I anticipate creating three loops, but the above premise is the same for all loops, just with different ranges. (I know a lastRow code could be used, but I'm not confident in having the last row be different for 3 sheets with varying row counts.)

Here is an example from the first loop I wrote, which runs Top -> bottom and ends up skipping every other line because it deletes the active row, cells shift up a row, then moves on to the next row.
**BrNoRng = range1** described above.

```vb
Dim x As Integer
Dim BrNo As String
Dim BrNoRng As Range
Dim c As Range, rng

Set BranchRange = Range("B2:B35")    'this range is in separate file
Set BrNoRng = Range("B2")         ' ^^ this range is in separate file

BrNo = BrNoRng.Value

'******Begin Loop 1***************
For x = 1 To 34      'Loop 1 is fine to run top -> bottom

    '******Begin Loop 2******************     'Loop 2 Needs to run Bottom -> Top    
    Sheets1.Activate      'Not actual name of the sheet, used as a placeholder sheet name, 
                       'this is where the rows need to delete
   
    Set rng = Range("C3:C2500")

    For Each c In rng.Rows
        If c.Value <> BrNoRng.Value Then
            c.Value.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next c
    '*****End loop 2**********

Next x
'*****End Loop 1*************
```

Comment: When you loop from bottom to top do `step -1` in your `for` loop.

Comment: `c.Value.EntireRow.Delete` should be `c.EntireRow.Delete`